How to use a for loop in Karate
I am using Karate gatling for performance testing, I am creating 50 random users and writing their mail ids in the files using karate.write() and I want to call each user one by one in a single script, with the admin login once, login of all the other users, adming log out, looks like karate for, foreach, repeat while are not working. Please provide inputs
Admin login (with jwt token)
Each user login
Read each of the files where mail ids are written (one by one)
Admin logout (with jwt token)
if I use the repeat of the feature file for each user then jwt token is getting duplicated, as I run the things in parallel.

This question is similar to: How to use for loop in karate. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
